# What's an intuitive understanding of diffusion capacitance?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, capacitance

[Diffusion capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_capacitance) often comes up in transistor design. It is one of the two main capacitances you see, the other being [the depletion layer capacitance.](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/pncap.htm) The depletion layer capacitance (per unit area) has a pretty straightforward explanation, that the opposite edges of the depletion layer have charge buildup on them and thus form a parallel plate capacitor.

But I can't find a great explanation for the diffusion capacitance anywhere. I can find *derivations* of the relevant equations, but it's more algebra manipulation than illuminating. The qualitative explanations are pretty vague. My textbook says it's "associated with the rearrangement of excess minority carriers in the diode in response to a change in applied voltage". [This source](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~bbathula/courses/SSDT/lect09.pdf) (PDF) says "the origin of the larger capacitance lies in the injected charge stored near the junction outside the transition region", which I find equally vague.

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) of capacitance to be "ability of a body to store an electrical charge", which seems pretty good, can anyone explain it?

Comment: In forward bias conditions, there are free carriers in the device. As the bias conditions change slightly, the carrier concentrations as a function of position need to adjust as well. This will be seen on the terminals as a capacitance change as the charge sloshes around. You apply a $\delta V$ and you get a $\delta Q$ - looks like capacitance to me.

Comment: Maybe you are asking for a physical understanding of diffusion coefficient. See this link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32628/